Htaccess for 2 php scripts running on the same site
How do I allow a /subfolder containing a forum php script to be accessible from the /public_html where the htaccess is located? There is also an htaccess in the forum subfolder too.
When I go to /community on my website the vendor php script installed in public_html says 404 error not found for the forum script. I need to have the vendor script allow access to the forum in the sufolder.

Your question is vague ... It is not clear what that "vendor script" does. Why it has to "allow" anything, how it is connected to that forum you mention. To me this reads like you simply want to rewrite incoming requests to the forum to that subfolder:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?community/?$ /subfolder [L]

Or:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?community/?$ /subfolder/forum.php [L]

Details depend on your setup, of course, the files actually required in that subfolder.
You can implement such rules inside the central http server's virtual host configuration. Or, if you do not have access to that (read: if you are using a cheap hosting provider instead of operating your own http server), you can use a distributed configuation file (often called ".htaccess"), if the consideration of such files is enabled in the http server's virtual host location . Thuse files come with a number of disadvantages, but might be the last option for some.
